# How to generate dynamic year list till current year in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I want to make a query for years list using PostgreSQL for my BIRT report's data set.

I want year list from 2012 to current year (as now 2018) so my required output should be like this:

```
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
```

Comment: `select generate_series(2012,extract(year from now())::int);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

smth like:

```
t=> select generate_series(2012,extract(year from now())::int);
 generate_series
-----------------
            2012
            2013
            2014
            2015
            2016
            2017
            2018
(7 rows)
```

should do

Comment: sure - my pleasure